# Is the entire road west of the Nile from Atbara to Omdurman tarred?

Tags: driving, sudan

I've broken up the route into 3 screenshots.

[image]

[image]

[image]

I'm talking of the road running west of the Nile (north in the 2nd image). Starting south west of Atbara and ending in Omdurman.

Google maps satellite shows sections which seem not-tarred / under construction.

Is the entire road tarred?

Comment: Google Maps doesn't show me satellite images detailed enough to determine the condition of the road with certainty. But I also see several bits where the road is probably not tarred, or paved, or anything but a depression in the sand.

Comment: Obviously, someone with actual Knowledge of the road is called for here.

Answer (score 3):

No.

I cycled this route from 25 - 27 Jan 2019

250km out of 312km are tarred.

The first 30km are tarred.

Then 50km of tracks, through villages, sometimes deep sand, difficult to know which tracks to follow as people seem to drive where they like. The locals advised to follow the power lines (which lead to Khartoum).

I've marked this section in red below.

[image]

Then tar for 50km to the turn off to Shendi. Easy to miss the start of the tar. Google maps and GPS helps to find the tar. Coordinates: 17.0260825, 33.6602214 from google maps and here a picture.

[image]

From the turn off to Khartoum it's basically tar for 175km. 12km in the Sabaloka game reserve are under construction.